# Trasnfer DataGrid data from a close Form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two WindowsForms Form1 and Form2. Form1 and Form2 have Both DataGrid. The second Form is populate from SqlCommand. The Form1 have Grid Custom.

This the Form1

```
public partial class OrderForm : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1Grid.CellDoubleClick += OrderGrid_CellDoubleClick;            
    }

    private void OrderGrid_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

this is the Form2

```
public partial class Form2: Form
{

    public ProductsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form2Grid.CellMouseDoubleClick += Form2Grid_CellMouseDoubleClick;
    }

    private void Form2Grid_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
     //What code here
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Object prd = new object();
        Form2Grid.DataSource = prd.Read(); // prd.Read() is SqlDataTable that populate the Grid in Form2
    }  
    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }      
}
```

That thing i want to do is. When i double click on GridRow on Form1, open the Form2 with populate from SqlCommand and when i double click on Form2 that row need to tranfer in form1 and populate the selected row on form1 and hide the form2. That needs to repeat until user end and do something doesnt matter what. At the end must have Form1 populated with the clicked rows from Form2.
Just this cycle Form1 -> doubleclick on row -> Form2 -> double click on row -> tranfer row on Form1 -> Hide Form2 and repeat as many times user wants.

If you need more explain i ll do.

Comment: Rather than posting your algorithm as text, people might be more inclined to help if you take a shot at writing the code you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose a property on Form2 (bad name by the way!) that contains the information to need to return, then after the `ShowDialog` call grab the data from the property and use it however you want in Form1.